# Class name not parsing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that finds the class name fc-id## which could be ex: fc-id3 or fc-id14

I turn this into fc-day##. The problem is it  something like fc-id14 becomes fc-day1 ... It seems only the first digit is parsed...

```
$(mondays).each(function () {
    var num = this.className.split(' ')[0].match(/fc-id(\d)/)[1];
    var clsnme = '.fc-day' + num;

    $(this).addClass('monday');
    $(clsnme).addClass('monday');
});
```

How can I get it to parse the entire number?

Comment: you are using the wrong regex, use `/fc-id(\d+)/` or `/fc-id(\d*)/`, first checks one or more digit while second checks 0 or more. Decide which one to use

Comment: `var num = this.className.split(' ')[0].replace('fc-id','');` do you really need a regular expression for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's giving you exactly what you're asking for. `\d` matches a single digit. If you want to match *multiple* digits, you need to use a quantifier like `*` (zero or more) or `+` (one or more):

```
/fc-id(\d+)/
```

Answer (score 2):

Match more than one number (`\d`):

```
var num = this.className.split(' ')[0].match(/fc-id(\d+)/)[1];
```

`\d` matches for exactly one digit, `\d+` matches one or more digits.